# Send List from Angular to Spring

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring

Iam trying to send an Object from angular to my spring to add a new product. The product has a list of prices and sizes. This is how it looks like in backend:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class ProductDto {

    private Long id;

    private Long secondId;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private MultipartFile img;

    private byte[] returnedImg;

    private Long categoryId;

    private String categoryName;

    private Long restaurantId;

    private Long userId;

    private List<SizePriceDto> sizePrices;


}
```

Controller class:

```
   @PostMapping("product/{categoryId}/{restaurantId}/{userId}")
    public GeneralResponse addProduct(@PathVariable Long categoryId, @PathVariable Long restaurantId, @PathVariable Long userId, @ModelAttribute ProductDto productDto) {
        GeneralResponse response = new GeneralResponse();
        try {
            return restaurantService.addProduct(categoryId, restaurantId, userId, productDto);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            response.setMessage("Sorry Something Wrong Happened.");
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Frontend:

```
      this.sizes.controls.forEach((sizeGroup, index) => {
        sizesAndPrices.push({
          size: sizeGroup.get('size').value,
          price: sizeGroup.get('price').value
        });
      });
      formData.append('sizePrices', '[{"size":"30","price":343},{"size":"frefgv","price":343}]');
```

And this is the error that i get when i submit the form in angular:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'productDto' on field 'sizePrices': rejected value [[{"size":"34","price":2342},{"size":"f4ef","price":3434}]]; codes [typeMismatch.productDto.sizePrices,typeMismatch.sizePrices,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productDto.sizePrices,sizePrices]; arguments []; default message [sizePrices]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'sizePrices'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.restaurant.dto.SizePriceDto' for property 'sizePrices[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

SizePriceDto Class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SizePriceDto {
    private String size;
    private Long price;
}
```

SizePrice Class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class SizePrice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String size;

    private Long price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

My request from angular:

https://i.postimg.cc/zfnXT4mT/image.png

I tried alot of methods but nothing works and i dont have any idea how to fix this error.

Comment: the error shows typeMismatch exception, you should check fields data type in class `SizePriceDto` and the json data you sent to the server, share the code for class `SizePriceDto` and copy paste the request body that sent to the server here if you want further help

Comment: I added all the information that i have now

Comment: It looks like Spring recognize the `sizePrices` as string and cannot serialize it into `List<SizePriceDto>` try changing the formData you append into object like this `fd.append('sizePrices', [{"size":"30","price":343},{"size":"frefgv","price":343}]);`

Comment: I initially tried using FormData to send an object to my backend, but FormData only accepts strings. As a result, I sent the ProductDto object without using FormData. However, this caused problems with the image, as the image file needs to be sent using FormData. To solve this issue, I converted the image to base64 and sent it that way. It took me a couple of days to realize that the backend wasn't able to recognize the list because of this issue.

Comment: here is the link for `FormData.append` documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append